# Laravel 5.6 set migration nullable foreign id

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-5.6

> This error popup:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ltfrbr10infosystem`.`franchises`, CONSTRAINT `franchises_operator_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`operator_id`) REFERENCES `operators` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

> Laravel Migrration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('franchises', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->integer('operator_id')->nullable()->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('operator_id')->references('id')->on('operators')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->string('case_number')->nullable();
        $table->string('business_address')->nullable();
        $table->date('date_granted')->nullable();
        $table->date('expiry_date')->nullable();
        $table->string('route_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('deno')->nullable();
        $table->integer('authorize_units')->nullable();
        $table->string('remarks')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I have tried this but still it gives me error

```
$table->integer('operator_id')->nullable()->unsigned()->change();
```

I also tried this

```
$table->integer('operator_id')->unsigned()->default(null);
```

How do I make operator_id foreign key default to null?

Answer (score 1):

If the data on your database is not important you could refresh your migrations and your database using

> php artisan migrate:refresh

This will rollback and migrate all your migrations again. Make sure you wrote the down method right,
also, you migration should look like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('franchises', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->unsignedInteger('operator_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('operator_id')->references('id')->on('operators')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

        $table->string('case_number')->nullable();
        $table->string('business_address')->nullable();
        $table->date('date_granted')->nullable();
        $table->date('expiry_date')->nullable();
        $table->string('route_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('deno')->nullable();
        $table->integer('authorize_units')->nullable();
        $table->string('remarks')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Other way to do it is creating a new migration like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('franchises', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->unsignedInteger('operator_id')->nullable()->change();


    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you get this error because the record you are trying to insert contains a wrong value for the column operator_id. This value is not a correct operator id and is not null (it could be 0, "null" or empty string, ...)

Can you paste here the exact SQL query which rises this error ?

Comment: i site the error above. The column operator_id record is empty

Comment: Do you get this error while running the migration itself ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside up function and run php artisan migrate:refresh --seed

```
public function up(){

    Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
    Schema::create('franchises', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('operator_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('operator_id')->references('id')->on('operators')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
    $table->string('case_number')->nullable();
    $table->string('business_address')->nullable();
    $table->date('date_granted')->nullable();
    $table->date('expiry_date')->nullable();
    $table->string('route_name')->nullable();
    $table->string('deno')->nullable();
    $table->integer('authorize_units')->nullable();
    $table->string('remarks')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();}
```

Comment: Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints(); still dont work

Comment: Edited Please check again

Answer (score 0):

you should use this

```
$table->foreign('operator_id')->references('id')->on('operators')->nullable()->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).